# Detect wrong decryption key while working with mcrypt functions in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, key, mcrypt

I've wrote the codes below to make an encryption and decryption mechanism. Everything works fine, but I would like to prevent showing unreadable characters if somebody enter a wrong key while decryption. Instead, I would like to show him a certain error message. How can I do it?
My PHP codes:

```
<?php

$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

function encrypt($plaintext,$key) {
    global $iv, $iv_size;
    $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    $ciphertext = $iv . $ciphertext;
    return base64_encode($ciphertext);
}

function decrypt($ciphertext_base64,$key) {
    global $iv, $iv_size;
    $ciphertext_dec = base64_decode($ciphertext_base64);
    $iv_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, 0, $iv_size);
    $ciphertext_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, $iv_size);
    return mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $ciphertext_dec, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv_dec);
}

echo decrypt(encrypt('Hello World','123'),'123');
// Correct key used for decryption and result will be `Hello world`

echo decrypt(encrypt('Hello World','123'),'321');
// Wrong key used for decryption and result will be something like :ŘI¨ĄěđŘcSNŔ¶¸˘ÚE‘Z‰ŃZŃ9

?>
```

Comment: In real life, how will you know that the decryption has been given the wrong key?? Unless you already know the correct answer to the decryption?? Which kind of defeats the point of encrypting anything if you or someone keeps the unencrypted data to use in a comparison to check the decryption.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I am writing an application that encrypt and decrypt data for people. They can see the origin data if they enter a correct key only. Otherwise, I must ask them to enter key again. To know what I mean, please use onetimesecret.com and create a one time link with a key. Then try to open that link using a wrong key and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, but my point is, the only way to know that the key is wrong is if you know what the key is. If I use **your** system to create **my secret**, I have to hope you do not keep the key. **OTHERWISE ITS NOT A SECRET** So **I definitely would not use your system or onetimesecret.com**

Comment: @RiggsFolly, yes you are right. Actually I don't know what is used mechanism in **onetimesecret.com**. However as you said, I have to avoid storing any raw data than can be returned easily by myself or others.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, what is your idea about what hanzi said? (Both method 1 and 2)

Comment: Method 2 sounds nice, with the hash in the encoded text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only detect whether a key was correct if you already know *something* about the plain text.

#### (Bad) Method 1: Add a static string to the plain text

You could modify your `encrypt()` function so that it always adds something to the plain text, e.g. `$plaintext = 'correct key' . $plaintext;`.

In your `decrypt()` function you could now check whether this string exists and remove it before returning.

You would have to replace the last line of `decrypt()` with this:

```
$decrypted_text = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $ciphertext_dec, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv_dec);
if (strpos($decrypted_text, 'correct key') === 0) {
    return substr($decrypted_text, strlen('correct key'));
} else {
    // key was wrong
    return false;
}
```

The problem here is that knowing part of the encrypted message potentially weakens the security of the encryption. So don't do that.

#### (Better) Method 2: Validate the plain text with a hash

Instead of modifying the plain text, you could just save a finger print (e.g. a SHA1 hash) of it.

Modify the `encrypt()` function like this:

```
return sha1($plaintext) . base64_encode($ciphertext);
```

And the `decrypt()` function like this:

```
function decrypt($ciphertext, $key) {
    global $iv, $iv_size;

    $fingerprint = substr($ciphertext, 0, 32);
    $ciphertext_base64 = substr($ciphertext, 32);

    $ciphertext_dec = base64_decode($ciphertext_base64);
    $iv_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, 0, $iv_size);
    $ciphertext_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, $iv_size);

    $decrypted_text = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $ciphertext_dec, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv_dec);
    if (sha1($decrypted_text) == $fingerprint) {
        return $decrypted_text;
    } else {
        // key was wrong
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's better to put the hash into the plaintext and encrypt it together. Doing it this way won't leak any information about the plaintext. Of course an altogether better alternative would be to use Encrypt-then-MAC, but it is harder to get it right. Reference: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac

Comment: I know this is a very old example, but this was one of the first examples that showed up when I was searching for a way to validate the same thing in some code I found.

This was a bad idea in 2015, and an even worse one in 2020. Please don't do it. SHA1'ing the plain text alongside the encrypted text is basically just an invitation to rainbow table the SHA.

This is basically just security through obscurity, and at worst a pretty big security flaw. Honestly the bad method was more secure.